# Resolving tenant connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, dbcontext

I'm trying to build a multi-tenant application in which tenants have their own DB's.

I've created a helper class like so:

```
public class Tenant
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

And within my `appsettings.json` I have:

```
{
 "Multitenancy": {
 "Tenants": [
   {
    "Name": "Tenant1",
    "ConnectionString": "server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS; database=Tenant1; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
   },
   {
    "Name": "Tenant2",
    "ConnectionString": "server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS; database=Tenant2; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Then in my `ApplicationDbContext` I have:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>
{
    private readonly Tenant _tenant;

    public ApplicationDbContext(Tenant tenant)
    {
        _tenant = tenant;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_tenant.ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

I added the db context in my `Startup`:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Unable to resolve service for type 'Tenant' while attempting to activate 'ApplicationDbContext'.
```

I don't understand what I've done wrong, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: how do you identify the current tenant to be able to inject it into your context?

Comment: @Nkosi You see because the application will be a single instance in which all tenants would use to access api's, I guess using the DNS is ruled out. I was thinking some sort of key stored against each tenant which a tenant will provide in a request and then this will be used to resolve the current tenant

Comment: Well then i suggest you have that info in a claim for the current request and use that to extract the desired connection string from the configuration. Your current design to try and inject without first working out the current tenant wont work

Comment: This now makes this question a bit broad.

Comment: You could have a Shared db where you could save a table lets say Tenant-DbName. You could have the connection string details in that table as well. With each request you would create this Shared DbContext and based on your request Tenant(Code or Id) you would grab the information about Request scope tenant.

Comment: @Nkosi Let's say I have information to resolve a tenant how would I inject this tenant into the application db context?

Comment: @KTOV you would first have to register the dependency at startup, but there is no request at that point.

Comment: @xargs-mkdir Thanks for the suggestion but it's out of scope of what I need. I don't like the idea of a shared db. It'd make rollbacks a lot more complex (if you wanted to rollback a specific tenant)

Comment: @Nkosi Does that mean building a connection string for the db based on the tenant isn't achievable if this was to be done per request?